# rides a bike to work while all of his friends drive cars instead

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

Is "instead" used properly in the following? If not, please explain.

> Joe rides a bike to work while all of his friends drive cars instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant. I don't see that it adds meaning, except maybe as emphasis. The word "while" already establishes a contrast between what the two groups do, and that contrast is the subject of the sentence:

[Merriam-Webster *while*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while)
2a : when on the other hand :WHEREAS
*easy for an expert, **while** it is dangerous for a novice*

[Lexico *while*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/while)
Whereas (indicating a contrast)
*one person wants out, **while** the other wants the relationship to continue*

Comment: You could say "Joe no longer rides his bike to work, but goes by car instead" (that is, in place of the bike).